# Google Maps Activity Authorization failure

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement my first google maps activity in demo android app. I have activated the API key on Developer's Console and copied it in the maps_api.xml file. I'm loading the activity with code:

```
Intent myInt = new Intent(view.getContext(), maps_activ.class);
startActivity(myInt);
```

The application launches and the activity loads with empty screen.
I get several error logs.

**On launch:**

*GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.*
*Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.*
*Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled*

**On startActivity:**

*Authentication failed on the server.
Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                         Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                                                        API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
                                                                                            Android Application (;): 13:10:51:FC:EB:51:16:E3:5.......etc.*

I have searched Stackoverflow but found old version fixes. Also watched the tutorial and followed the steps but something is going wrong.

**Edit: It's asking for Google Maps Android API v2, I can't find such in google developer's console.**

Answer (score 0):

The reason was, I had two resource files, one in debug and another in release. The manifest file was reading one from debug, which in fact was empty.